# Is there a way to connect a serial cable to my pi while it is connected to my breadboard?

Tags: pi-4, sensor, putty, breadboard

Currently I have my pi connected to my breadboard using a cobbler and breakout cable so I can connect some sensors (DHT22 and BMP280). Is there are way I can also connect my serial cable to it so I can also access putty?

Comment: yes, there probably is a way

Comment: yes, use GPIO14 and GPIO15

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. For this you need to look up the pinout of your RPi.

Here is one for the RPi4, but iirc they are all the same. ([source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/))

[image: pinout]

Now we have to look what protocol you need. Most common it's UART, I2C or SPI.

If you need `UART`, we look for `TXD` and `RXD` -> `GPIO14` and `GPIO15`

If you need `I2C`, we look for `SDA` and `SCL` -> `GPIO2` and `GPIO2`

If you need `SPI`, we look for `MOSI`, `MISO`, `SCLK` and `CS` (chip select, I don't know why it's called `CE0` on RPi) -> `GPIO10`, `GPIO9`, `GPIO11` and `GPIO8`